# Save and retrieve RichTextBox.Document from/to SQL?

Tags: wpf, sql-server-2005, richtextbox

I want to use a Wpf RichTextBox to edit data and resave it to SQL field.
I need of course the text to be saved as rich text, not just simple text of course.

1. What data-type should be best for storing in SQL server (2005 - forget about file stream)?
2. How do I save/retrieve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can save the document to a XAML string using `XamlWriter` :

```
        StringWriter wr = new StringWriter();
        XamlWriter.Save(richTextBox.Document, wr);
        string xaml = wr.ToString();
```

You can then save the XAML string to a the database like any other text.

To reload it from a XAML string, use `XamlReader` :

```
        FlowDocument doc = XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as  FlowDocument;
```

Comment: Hi, @Thomas Levesque. +1 for this answer. It work for me. But I have a problem to handle  events of element after retrieving from database. Please, look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123349/handle-hyperlink-click-event-after-load-from-database-in-c-sharp-richtextbox

Answer (score 3):

The datatype in SQL should probably be NVARCHAR(MAX): Nvarchar means you can store unicode, and MAX means you can store unlimited amounts, (well up to 2GB anyway) of data.

Comment: Would you recoment to save it varbinary?

Comment: varbinary is typicaly for images, or other byte streams.

Comment: What is better for performance?
I am not sure if images will be needed.
But if varbinary's performance usage <= varchar, than I prefer varchar, cuz I want to make it harded to read the sql raw data.
The thing is I donno how to exrecat/load the FlowDocument from byte[]